# NulllReferenceException rendering Html.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following code in my view:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                            {
   using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm"}))
   {
      @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
      <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
    }
 }
```

When rendering the page, it's throwing NullReferenceException, but I'm unable to figure out what's causing this. Stacktrace shows that exception is happening in this peace of code:

> en ASP._Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml.Execute() en C:\Proyectos\SDC_Web_Sistema_Documental_Centralizado\OpenText\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:línea 60
>      en System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>      en System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>      en System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
>      en System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
>      en System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
>      en System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>      en System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
>      en System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
>      en System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @Igor No, this is not a duplicate, as long as this is happening in a razor view and no object instantiation is done in this code. That answer doesn't solve my problem

Comment: The code you have shown cannot generate that exception. Its dues to code you have not shown

Comment: @StephenMuecke This is where vs is stopping. Here the stacktrace makes it clear, in index.cshtml, line 60:

   en ASP._Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml.Execute() en C:\Proyectos\SDC_Web_Sistema_Documental_Centralizado\OpenText\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:línea 60
   en System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   en System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   en System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)...

Comment: You need to show the whole view (the code you have shown does not throw an error)

Comment: It is a duplicate. There is even a section in the answer about NRE's in Razor views (which is what your question is). NRE's are almost always generic (99% of the time). I recommend you read the answer and apply the troubleshooting tips to your problem.

Comment: @StephenMuecke But could it happen that the exception is been thrown somewhere else even if VS stops in this line, and stacktrace points to this line?

Comment: Your code keep sensitive data? why don't you copy all html code?

Comment: Yes (and razor does not always report the error line correctly anyway). The question will be closed as a dupe, but you might as well show the view.